# Is there a definitive guide to connect Cassandra and Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, nosql, cassandra

I have searched all over the Internet for a guide to connect Hadoop and Cassandra, and even the "Cassandra: The Definitive Guide" does not provide any pointer, claiming that it is "outside the scope of this book".

Therefore, is there any hidden definitive guide for this?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some documentation located here:

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport

Although, I'm not sure I would call it a definitive guide. If you already have both cassandra clusters and hadoop clusters set up, your best bet is to start there and then ask questions (irc, mailing list, etc). If you are new to either cassandra or hadoop I would start by familiarizing yourself with those projects separately before attempting to connect the two.

There is also the DataStax Enterprise product ( http://www.datastax.com/products/enterprise ) which combines hadoop and cassandra into a single application. http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/datastax_enterprise/index

DISCLAIMER: You should note both that I work for DataStax and that DataStax Enterprise is not open source and not free (although it is free for development/non-production use).